# Errors trying to convert type [Any] to JSON with Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, casting

I'm trying to convert an object type `[Any]` to a JSON or something I can use to access the attributes.

**Steps:**

1. I call a function from a library to connect to a bluetooth device and retrieve data from it's memory:

```swift
device.getMemoryData(totalCount: { (count) in
       print("There are \(count) elements in the memory")
    }, dataArray: { (data) in
      print("DATA --> \(data)")
      self.processReceivedData(data)
      // Here is where I receive the [Any] object 
    })
```

The received object printed in the step 1 conforms the following:

```swift
[{
    side = 0;
    dataID = 07ebcd0070bf9a8116a8898e673e96e4;
    valueA = 69;
    valueC = 60;
    valueD = 0;
    irregular = 0;
    angleChange = 4;
    startAngle = 34;
    valueB = 106;
    time = "2015-01-01 13:33:00 +0000";
},
{
    side = 0;
    dataID = 0cf80347a86013689586d01d1d80fca5;
    valueA = 69;
    valueC = 60;
    valueD = 0;
    irregular = 0;
    angleChange = 2;
    startAngle = 37;
    valueB = 106;
    time = "2015-01-01 15:06:00 +0000";
}]
```

2. Try to access the information that the object contains:

I try with `JSONSerialization`:

```swift
function processReceivedData(data:[Any]) {
  guard let processedData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: []) as? [[String: Any]] else {
      print("ERROR")
      return
    }
 print("JSON: \(processedData)")
// Run error when trying to serialize: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)'
*** First throw call stack:
}
```

I also try to iterate through it using the following `for` but I get a compile error:

```swift
function processReceivedData(data:[Any]) {
 for item in data {
      for (id, object) in item {
        print("ID: \(id), Object: \(object)")
      }
    }
}
// Compile error: Type 'Any' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'
```

I need to access to the data to check which position have the oldest timestamp and the take the values. How can I access to the data?

Comment: Why there're `=`, should be `:` instead ?

Comment: @T.Wei It comes that way from the device I retrieve it.

Comment: @T.Wei I just find in the library that I'm using the type definition of the object. `typedef void(^BlockBachArray)(NSArray *bachArray);`

Comment: you are trying to serialize It, but the data is not in a json format. what kind of device is that?

Comment: @FRIDDAY it is a bluetooth device. I use a library to connect to it and retrieve the data. It comes that way.

Comment: your print is an array not json structure see below correct json

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please edit your question and add how you are iterating over your dictionaries `processedData` and how you are creating your measurements object. **Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.** https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LeoDabus I update the question. Let me know if I have to add more data

Comment: does it pass the guard or does it print "ERROR"?

Comment: you should use a `do try catch` and `print(error)` bobject. if you use try? you are saying I don't care what the error is just return nil in case of failure.

Comment: @LeoDabus it doesn't pass the guard neither print the "ERROR". It throws: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)' *** First throw call stack: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Comment: Is there any documentation about `device.getMemoryData` still a bit confusing is data a `NSArray` or `[Any]`?

Comment: `if let data = [[String: Any]] {}` should work since what you have is a `NSArray`, ie, JSON already parsed into basic CocoaTouch objects (NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString, etc.). Quickly written: `if let array = data as? [[String: Any]] { for aDictionary in array { for aKeyValue in aDictionary { let aKey = aKeyValue.key; let aValue = aKeyValue.value; print("ID: \(aKey), Object: \(aValue)") } } }`

Comment: `[Any]` is the wrong type. This is clearly an array of specific and consistent objects, not an array of "any possible type, including view controllers, views, file managers, and other things that cannot be turned into JSON." It looks like `getMemoryData` is incorrectly implemented, and fixing that should be the first step if possible. Where does this method come from?

Comment: @user10816637 ok so seems to that dataID is an NSString with an hexa value, time is NSDate,  side = 0 can be a Boolean, NSString or NSNumber. The same applies to irregular. Guessing angleChange, startAngle, values A,B, C, and D are probably NSNumbers and can be converted to Int.

Comment: @user10816637 try something like this  https://gist.github.com/leodabus/a1452601ad4a846442a59cefea2c554c

Comment: Hi @LeoDabus , answering to your question `getMemoryData`returns an `typedef void(^BlockBachArray)(NSArray *bachArray);`. When implementing the method, Xcode autosugest type `[Any]`

Comment: Hi @Larme, I've try your solution. At least I could print all key values pairs. I couldn't try anything else.

Comment: @LeoDabus I'll take a look of your gist later, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented, your `data` is an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`. You have no need to *convert to JSON* *to access the attributes*.

Try this:

```
func processReceivedData(data:[Any]) {
    for item in data {
        if let item = item as? [String: Any] {
            for (id, object) in item {
                print("ID: \(id), Object: \(object)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Unexpected element: \(item)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus, I do not use `AnyHashable` where `[String: Any]` do work. No bluetooth device directly generates `NSDictionary`. The dictionary must be generated by _the library_ and I cannot think of any library using non-string key. Please tell me if you know a bluetooth library which returns a dictionary with non-string keys.

Comment: @LeoDabus, have you read the error message carefully? `'Invalid type in JSON write (__NSTaggedDate)'` `JSONSerialization` throws an Exception (not an Error) when an `NSDate` is included in the data tree.

Comment: @LeoDabus, create an `NSDictionary` and see how various strings or dates are represented in its `description`.

Comment: I finally solve the situation with this solution. Thank you all! Sorry if it was a silly question but I was really lose with this one.